# Posting data using hidden form

Tags: php, ajax

I gont some help from SO previously. But there is some issue here.

```
var userid="12";                    
                        var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'></form>");
                        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+userid+'" />'); 
                        $('body').append($form);
                        window.form1.submit();
```

start.php

```
<?php
 $x=$_POST['userid'];
?>
```

What wrong here?

it gives error on start.php

```
Notice: Undefined index: userid in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testCase2/start.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using $form as variable but  in append using only form.append.
 Please change it to $form.append. Please check the code below. hope it should work.

```
           var userid="12";                    
           var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'></form>");
           $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+userid+'" />'); 
           $('body').append($form);
           window.form1.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['userid'];` is not set and dont use `var` in this case, there is no such variable `userid` in `POST` array. You can use:

```
if( isset( $_POST['userid'] ) ){
    $x=$_POST['userid'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `var` from php

```
<?php
  $x=$_POST['userid'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just access it as

```
<?php

 $x=$_POST['userid'];
?>
```

and not `var $x;`

and your **`<form>`** should be like this

```
var userid="12";                    
                        var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'>");
                        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'+userid+'" /></form>'); 
                        $('body').append($form);
                        window.form1.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You define `var $form`, but then call it just `form` -- you need a consistent variable name.  By the way, `$form` is a little confusing and likely to cause problems in debugging; try something like `objForm` for clarity.

Also, delete the `var` from your PHP and use `isset()`, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this method, moving hidden input inside the form tag.

```
     var $form = $("<form id='form1' method='post' action='start.php'><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='"+userid+"' /></form>");
      $('body').append($form);
      window.form1.submit();


 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
      $x=$_POST['userid'];
   }
 ?>
```